# Can C++ use local variables inside a function whose type is automatically inferred from the function return type?

Tags: c++, return, decltype, inferred-type

My question: Say I'm defining a function in C++ (or in C).  Is there anything similar to C++'s *auto* or *decltype* that I can use inside the function definition in order to declare a local variable with type inferred from the return type of the function that I'm defining?

Example:
A common coding pattern in C and C++ is

```
SomeType foo() {
   SomeType x;
   // ... do something to x ...
   return x;
}
```

And I'm hoping to infer the second *SomeType* instead of typing it in explicitly.
The following doesn't work, but I was hoping I could do something in this spirit

```
SomeType foo() {
   decltype(return) x;  //<-- infer the function return type, which here is SomeType
   // ... do something to x ...
   return x;
}
```

For simple return types it's not a big deal, but when return types are complicated (say the return type is a template class with lots of template parameters), it would be nice (and less error-prone) to not have to repeat that type definition inside the function.

I'd also like to not have to change the function definition to accomplish this.  So, while in the example above it could work to change *SomeType* to a macro, or perhaps make *foo* a template function and *SomeType* a template parameter, really I'm looking to see if in general I can infer a type specifically from the return type of the surrounding function.

Maybe the answer is "no it's not possible", which is fair, but I'd like to know one way or the other.

Comment: You can make the return type `auto` and use the actual type once inside the function.

Comment: @chris this requires C++14 or something like this right?

Comment: @pqnet, Yes, I was going to say that, but apparently I didn't.

Comment: In C++11, you could use `decltype(foo())` or brace-initialization in the return statement to avoid the duplication of the name of the return type. In simple lambdas (= only a return statement), the return type can be deduced, too (and this is relaxed in almost all C++11 compilers I know to lambdas with more than just a return statement).

Comment: @dyp I think in lambdas also C++11 allows not specifying return type (it is assumed to be `decltype` of the returned expression)

Comment: @pqnet In strict C++11, lambdas w/o trailing return type can have their return type deduced (via the rules for `auto`, not `decltype`) IFF they consist of only a single return statement: `[]{ return 42; }` returns an `int`, `[]{ int x = 42; return x; }` should not compile (return type is `void`). But of the compilers I know, only VS2010 uses those rules. For details, see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#975

Answer (score 6):

In C++11:

```
SomeType foo()
{
    decltype(foo()) x;
```

The expression `foo()` has the same type as the return value of `foo`.